# how to make visible other components in transparent UIVIEW in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I have used a UIVIEW . I want to make transparent the UIVIEW. But when I want to chage alpha 0.0  from storyboard for make UIVIEW transparent, textfield, label and other component also transparent. I want to make transparent  UIVIEW, not other component of the view. Here is the image

[image]

Please help me to make visible other components in UIVIEW transparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `UIView`'s `backgroundColor` to `UIColor.clear`.

Comment: TheGreate, Thanks it is working. I have used like uiview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the alpha of the UIView, you can make the background color of your UIView as white with alpha component 0.5 or something

```
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

If you want it to be completely transparent, you can set backgroundColor to clear from storyboard as well as code.

```
myView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the transparency not of the `UIView` itself, but of its 
background color.

For example:

[image]

I set the color of the `UIView` transparent, while the `UILabel` remained its settings.

In order to create a semi transparent color, you can use the following code:

```
yourView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Main.Storyboard** and select the view you want to make transparent.

From the **Attribute Inspector** select background color as custom.

Then set your desired color and decrease the percentage of **Opacity** of the color.

[image]